# How to show the value of the error bars generated by seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to visualize some data using seaborns. I am using a catplot that is set to be a bar plot. I have it showing the error bars to be the standard deviation. I want to know what value it is using for the mean and standard deviation it is using in the visualization, however I do not know how to retrieve that information from the plot. How would I go about getting that information?

```
bar_graph = seaborn.catplot(x="x", y="y", hue="z", data=data, ci="sd", capsize=0.1, kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to get that data from the plot generated by seaborn would not be impossible, but would be very cumbersome, as seaborn does not return the artists that it creates and `catplot()` can generate a number of subplots, etc.

However, I expect you don't need to get the data from the plot, you can get them directly from the dataframe, can't you? This simple demonstration shows that the plot and the calculated values do match:

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.catplot(x='sex',y='age',hue="class", data=titanic, ci="sd", capsize=0.1, kind="bar")
```

[image]

```
titanic.groupby(['sex','class'])['age'].describe()[['mean','std']]

                mean        std
sex     class       
female  First   34.611765   13.612052
        Second  28.722973   12.872702
        Third   21.750000   12.729964
male    First   41.281386   15.139570
        Second  30.740707   14.793894
        Third   26.507589   12.159514
```